# How to convert BigQuery Struct Schema string to Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion, google-bigquery

I have extracted the schema of my BigQuery table from the "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" table. I get the list of all the columns in the table in a proper Javascript Object format except of the "Struct" and "Array" data types. I need a clean way to convert the "Struct" and "Array" string into a javascript object.

I am working with NodeJS v11.2 I have written a small regex which extracts the following. But it doesn't seem right to split the string and iterate through each word until I get the output. I need a cleaner way to solve this.

```
let structString = "STRUCT<name STRING, email STRING, time_sec INT64, tz_offset INT64, date STRUCT<seconds INT64, nanos INT64>>";

let _structSchema = structString.match(/STRUCT<([^)]+)>/)[1];

console.log(_structSchema); // name STRING, email STRING, time_sec INT64, tz_offset INT64, date STRUCT<seconds INT64, nanos INT64>
```

I need to write a recursive function which will parse though the string and give me the output in following manner.

```
{
  "name": "STRING",
  "email": "STRING",
  "time_sec": "INT64",
  "tz_offset": "INT64",
  "date": {
    "seconds": "INT64",
    "nanos": "INT64"
  }
}
```

The function should run irrespective of the depth/hierarchy of the nested structs/arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regex can be good to tokenise the input string, but you'll need more logic to perform the actual parsing.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
function parse(structString) {
    let tokenizer = /([a-z_]\w*)|\S|$/gi;
    
    function next(identifier, expected) {
        let match = tokenizer.exec(structString);
        function error(expected) {
            throw `Expected ${expected} but got ${match[0]} at ${match.index}`;
        }
        match[0] = match[0] || "<EOF>";
        if (identifier && !match[1]) error(identifier);
        if (expected && !expected.includes(match[0])) error(expected.join(" or "))
        return match[0];
    }
    
    function getType() {
        let fieldType = next("type identifier or STRUCT or ARRAY");
        if (fieldType === "STRUCT") {
            next(null, ["<"]);
            fieldType = {};
            do {
                fieldType[next("field identifier")] = getType();
            } while (next(null, [",", ">"]) === ",");
        } else if (fieldType === "ARRAY") {
            next(null, ["<"]);
            fieldType = [getType()];
            next(null, [">"]);
        }
        return fieldType;
    }
    
    let result = getType();
    next(null, ["<EOF>"]);
    return result;
}

// Sample input & call
let structString = "STRUCT<name STRING, email STRING, time_sec INT64, tz_offset INT64, date STRUCT<seconds INT64, nanos INT64>, phones ARRAY<STRING>>";
let obj = parse(structString);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access Google Cloud Console from your environment, consider running something like: `bq show --format=pretty project:dataset.table` or `bq show --format=prettyjson project:dataset.table`.  You would still need to parse the results for your purposes, but the nesting is already done for you.